# Can you better explain the 50%+1 rule for token crowd sales?

Tags: tokens

I'm a bit confused about having to keep 50% of the token in reserve for the crowd sale. The documents don't really fully explain it.

Question: if I have a token with a total supply of 100 and I hold 25 and send 25 to my other wallet, "address a",  and I then send the other 50 to "contact c" for a crowd sale, how many tokens can I offer in the crowd sale contract?

Can I offer all 50 or only 25?

Sorry, I didn't mean for that to sound like an SAT question, I just don't understand how many tokens I need to issue total.

Comment: What are you referencing?

Comment: Source: https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale -------- I have 100 gadgets. Why not sell them all?

This creates the danger that someone controlling 50%+1 of all the tokens will be able to send all the funds to themselves. You can try to create special code on the association contract to prevent these hostile takeovers, or you can instead have all the funds sent to a simple address. To simplify we are simply selling off half of all the gadgets: if you want to further decentralize this, split the remaining half between trusted organizations.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Every crowd sale is different. The ethereum.org page is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing "tokens" and "ether" and "hash power." My memory has people calling "ether" tokens a long time ago, but since the ERC20 token has come onto the scene, that has lessened. People don't really call "ether" a "token" any more, although it is one. These days (you're reading nearly two year old documents), a token is an ERC20 token.

I haven't read the referenced documents in a while, but concerning the 51% thing my guess is that you're confusing the 51% attack idea (see mining) and a 51% voting power in something like a DAO. This is the same idea as in any situation where people vote based on some sort of holdings. In a DAO, anyone who owns more than 51% of the "tokens" (ERC20 tokens) would be able to vote anything to happen that they wanted. In the case of mining, if a miner owned 51% of the hash power, they could "vote" to take all the "ether."

(By the way--it's not really 51%. It's 50% plus 1 vote--a simple majority.)

Looks like you're relatively new. Welcome. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you're right, I think maybe they are referring to a DAO contract but for some reason that section is in the crowdsales part of the docs. Anyway, thanks for explaining things. I'm not going to worry about it any more :)

Comment: Dear Thomas, I found out your comment here because I was looking for the same thing. I was wondering, can you expand more on what you mean by "voting power"? Does that mean that people with 51% voting power can call functions accessible only to the contract owner?

Comment: @Cristian No. it just means they could outvote any other group of people. But it doesn’t mean they can do anything. The smart contract will have its own set of rules. If those rules allow the contract to be upgraded, anyone with 51% could upgrade it and then take all the ether if they wanted to but 51% voting power on a DAO does not give you any ability to change the way the smart contract behaves.